# Can't create schema for SQL Server CE using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-ce

When I am creating a schema for SQL Server CE using Nhibernate with this code:

```
Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard
            .ConnectionString(c => c.Is("Data Source=" + file))
            .Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect>()
            .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver>()
            .ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NHibernateSessionFactory>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildSessionFactory();  

private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
    {
       // new SchemaExport(config).Drop(false, true);
        //new SchemaExport(config).Create(true, true);

         //If DB File does not exists, create it.
        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(databaseFileName));
            SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source="+ file);
            engine.CreateDatabase();
            // this NHibernate tool takes a configuration (with mapping info in)
            // and exports a database schema from it
            new SchemaExport(config).Execute(false, true, false);
            //FormulasDAO.AddDefaultFormulaCollection();
        }
        else
        {
            new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true);
        }
    }
```

I got an exception like this

> An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check    PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

Inner exception is

> The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe could not be found. Ensure that the
>   assembly System.Data.SqlServerCe is located in the application
>   directory or in the Global Assembly Cache. If the assembly is in
>   the GAC, use  element in the application
>   configuration file to specify the full name of the assembly.

Help for this problem.

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear. Have you tried to following its instructions? What happened?

Comment: Yes I checked in the GAC, the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll was there and i set copy local true to this dll reference, No use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the problem was, in GAC there are 2 version of dlls so Nhibernate didnt know which dll need to use because NHibernate taking the dll from GAC using dll name only not using version name.

So need to tell NHibernate in the AppConfig

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<qualifyAssembly partialName="System.Data.SqlServerCe" fullName="System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts